# send email using powershell from command prompt

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

i'm using this powershell script to send emails:

```
param($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)

$Username = 'user@gmail.com';
$Password = 'pass';
$emailMsg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMsg.From = $EmailFrom
$emailMsg.To.Add($EmailTo)
$emailMsg.Subject = $Subject
$emailMsg.Body = $Body
$smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
$smtpClient.Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
$smtpClient.Port = 587
$smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true
$smtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtpClient.Send($emailMsg);
write-host "Mail Sent"
```

Calling it from command prompt like this works (I send the email to myself and I get in my inbox):

```
powershell -command "& {C:\path\sendGmailPSS.ps1 -EmailFrom mail -EmailTo mail2 -Subject 'test' -Body 'test'}"
```

But putting it in a bat file like this:

```
@echo off

powershell -command "& {C:\path\sendGmailPSS.ps1 -EmailFrom %1 -EmailTo %2 -Subject '%~3' -Body '%~4'}"
```

and calling it like this:

```
sendGmail.bat mail mail2 "test" "test"
```

doesn't work (I send the email to myself and even though in cmd I get the "Mail Sent" message, I don't get anything in my inbox)

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: i did a quick test with your code and (on windows 10) it works just as expected. what error do you get?

Comment: Please always tell the details of how it doesn't work in the question. Nothing happens or returns error message. Instead of saying just 'doesn't work'.

Comment: I don't get any error messages, I send the email to myself and even though in cmd I get the "Mail Sent" message, I don't get anything in my inbox.

Comment: Why aren't you using the built in CMDlet Send-MailMessage?

Comment: because this is my first powershell script, and the first thing appeared on google when searching I'll look into the cmdlet. After retrying again today, it working now... Thanks for your comments!